# Which known ephemeral ports do games use?

Tags: networking

Does anyone have a list of known ephemeral ports or games with configurable ephemeral ports so that I can create QoS rules? An ephemeral port is the source port used by the game client, and not the remote server port that most documentation refers to.

Comment: @kalina this question seems to be more about the client more so than the games it provides

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical details of how Steam works. I believe it would be better suited for [su] than here.

Answer (score 2):

[Steam uses the following ports](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711):

#### Steam Client

- UDP 27000 to 27015 inclusive (Game client traffic)
- UDP 27015 to 27030 inclusive (Typically used for Matchmaking and HLTV)
- TCP 27014 to 27050 inclusive (Used for Steam product and update downloads)

#### Dedicated or Listen Servers

- TCP 27015 (SRCDS and GoldSrc RCON port)

#### Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat

- UDP 3478 (Outbound)
- UDP 4379 (Outbound)
- UDP 4380 (Outbound)

As stated in the linked article, ports required for Steam can not be re-mapped to HTTP or reconfigured to a custom port range.

Comment: Does it really matter if the port is ephemeral or not? Just open these ports and be done with it.

Comment: "Open a port" utterly meaningless and colloquial phrase? If you say so.... Well, I understand that you want your network secure, so I try to find out as much as possible.